# Why does jQuery Expander stop working once you've loaded new text from Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, expander

I'm using jQuery Expander to truncate some text (adding 'read more' button). It works fine on default text, but once I load up some fresh content via Ajax the plugin doesn't work anymore (on the newly-loaded text).

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Code?? You may need to reload the plugin for the text again. You also may need to contact the plug-in creator.

Comment: The new text is probably not registered with the plugin. Calling the the plugin again (after ajax call is complete)  should fix it

Comment: Are you calling the expander code on any event of the elements which come through Ajax. If so try using live. You can find it at - http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: Exactomondo. Had to re-bind the plugin on the AjaxSuccess callback. Thanks folks!

Comment: If possible, please add the answer to this question and accept it, this will help for stackoverflow users in future..

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by using $('.....').expander('destroy');